# Update text button not working in axios.put request - NodeJS ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sqlite, express

I have a web board where I add posts with axios.post, delete them with axios.delete however can't manage to update them by pressing the update button (it's like doesn't respond at all), related to axios.put request.

I'm pretty sure the problem should lay in the script.js file because I do update the posts if using PUT in Postman, by selecting the related "id" of each entry, as expected. I'm going around this for quite a long time already, so please any hints and/or ideas of why my button doesn't update will be more than welcome.

Will drop down below just the index and script of the code because, as I mentioned, the backend seems to work alright.

Thanks a million in advance!

```
# script.js

displayPerceptions() 

function _(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

function displayPerceptions() {

    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/perceptions').then((res) => {

        var rows = res.data
        console.log(rows)
        _('rs').innerHTML = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            let txt = rows[i].text;
            let id = rows[i].id;
            const d = new Date(rows[i].created_at);
            d.addHours(1)
            _('rs').innerHTML += `
            <article class="message">
            
            <div class="message-header">
                <p style='color:white;'>Percepción #${id}</p>
                <button class="delete" aria-label="delete" onclick="removeData(${id})"></button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="message-body">
            <textarea onchange="alert('Actualizado!')" "changeTextArea(this)" id="txt">${txt}</textarea>
            <button id="txt" class="update" aria-label="update" onclick="updateData(${txt})">Editar Percepción</button>
            <div><small>${d.toLocaleString()}</small></div>
            </div>
            </article>
            `;
        }

        
    })
}

function addPerception(text) {
    let payload = { text: text };
    console.log('script ' + payload.text)
    let res = axios.post('http://localhost:3000/perceptions', payload);
    let data = res.data;
    console.log(data);
}

function updatePerception(text) {
    let payload = { text: text };
    console.log('script ' + payload.text)
    let res = axios.put('http://localhost:3000/perceptions/:id' , payload);
    let data = res.data;
    console.log(data);
}  
    
function removePerception(id) {
    let res = axios.delete('http://localhost:3000/perceptions/' + id);
    let data = res.data;
    console.log(data);
}

//IMPLEMENT ABOVE CREATED FUNCTIONS 'ADD', 'REMOVE', 'UPDATE'

function postData(id){
    let s = document.getElementById(id);
    addPerception(s.value);
    console.log(s.value);
    setTimeout(displayPerceptions, 1000);
    s.value = ''
}

function updateData(id){
    let s = document.getElementById(id);
    updatePerception(s.value);
    console.log(s.value);
    setTimeout(displayPerceptions, 1000);
    s.value = ''
}
    
function removeData(id){
    removePerception(id);
    setTimeout(displayPerceptions, 1000);
}

Date.prototype.addHours = function(h) {
    this.setTime(this.getTime() + (h*60*60*1000));
    return this;
}
```

```
# index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mi Rincón</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script defer type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg-img">
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column has-text-centered offset-one-quarter">
                <div class="card">
                    <header class="card-header has-text-centered">
                      <p >
                        <h1 class="card-header-title has-text-centered title is-3 has-text-link-dark">
                          Mi Rincón
                        </h1>
                      </p>
                    </header>
                    <section><p class="subtitle is-inline mt-3">Publicar pensamiento:</p></section>
                    <div class="card-content">
                      <div class="wrapper text-center">
                        <textarea id="txt" rows="3" placeholder="Escribe aquí..."></textarea>
                        <div class="text-l">
                            <button class="button button is-link is-light" onclick="postData('txt')">Publicar</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div id="rs" class="wrapper"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have `onclick="updateData(${txt})"` Did you mean `onclick="updateData(${id})"`?

Comment: For your put request the URL you have used is "http://localhost:3000/perceptions/:id". Are you expecting to `:id` to be replaced by the actual ID?  Currently it looks like you are only submitting  the id in the body of the request not the path.

Comment: @James tried that and I think I'm more meant to update/edit the variable `txt `which is `txt = rows[i].text`.

Comment: @faire actually I'm trying to only edit the text value or `txt`, not the `id`. I've read that in the `PUT call` you need to address the id of the entry to makes changes on the body, etc.

Comment: Are you able to see the put request in the network tab of your browser's dev tools? If you can see the request, try comparing  that to what you generated with postman

Comment: @faire as a matter fact I'm not able to see this (it's like idle), only see triggering the `onchange="alert('Actualizado!')"` pop up, unlike when I click the post or delete buttons. That's why I believe there's something missing in the `script.js` part, to make the button actually functional.